# Too much space between badge icon and number of badges

Tags: bug, design, badges

An (perhaps unintended) consequence of the new design (e.g. here on Meta Stack Exchange) is that the spacing between the badge icon (the gold, silver or bronze dot) and the number of badges is increased. In my opinion too much: in the figure below, the number of gold badges (11) is closer to the silver dot than the 79.

[image]

It happens at more locations, e.g. in the top bar:

[image]

although there the text is in the same color as the badge itself, so it's less annoying.

I prefer the old way, as shown e.g. on [beta sites](https://chess.stackexchange.com/):

[image] [image]

<sub>(tested on the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS High Sierra, and Chrome on Windows 10)</sub>

Comment: you got 34 thousands gold badges, what are you complaining about? :P

Comment: heh :) at least it's better than on [codegolf.se] where the badges aren't visible *at all*